# Recover Whatsapp messages that I accidentally deleted

Tags: google-drive-api, backup, whatsapp, restore

I accidentally deleted a whatsapp chat, and I want to recover it.
I have the setting so that google drive backups my data, but I didn't really understand the process fully and as the messages (about 100k of them) were getting deleted, I backedup my data, and it seems that the new backup that has been overwritten on google drive doesn't include the deleted chat, so even if I uninstall and reinstall whatsapp, it won't recover that.

I've seen that it's possible to recover it if it's stored in the internal drive, which I didn't find except older ones from 2 years ago. I think it stopped backing up on my internal drive when I started backing up on google drive.

My first thoughts is to do something similar to the google drive backup files as for the internal files; find the backup version that preserves my deleted chat, and change the file names so that it becomes the backup file instead.

An alternative is to backup the 2 years old file in the internal drive, but it's in a different phone number as I moved country, so it's complicated as well.

Can I ask help for this?

I saw that by changing the backup files' names as in this instruction;
Restore a less recent local backup
If you want to restore a local backup that isn't the most recent one, you'll need to do the following:
Download a file manager app.
In the file manager app, navigate to your local storage or sdcard > WhatsApp > Databases. If your data isn't stored on the SD card, you might see "internal storage" or "main storage" instead.
Rename the backup file you want to restore from msgstore-YYYY-MM-DD.1.db.crypt12 to msgstore.db.crypt12. It's possible that an earlier backup might be on an earlier protocol, such as crypt9 or crypt10. Don't change the number of the crypt extension.
Uninstall and reinstall WhatsApp.
Tap RESTORE when prompted.

I can restore my messages, but I was wondering if there was a way to get into the whatsapp-backup file in google drive. I couldn't really search inside it or anything although I see its existence in the google drive.